# Firebug with HTTP/2 push promise

Tags: firefox, firebug, http2

Is it possible to view HTTP/2 push promise frames in Firefox with Firebug? I'm using nghttp2 to create a small HTTP/2 web proxy and I'd like to be able to view and sent push promise frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug (at least up to 2.0.x) only displays normal network requests and requests coming from the cache.

I assume PUSH_PROMISE and other HTTP/2 frames are currently not exposed by the [internal](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c87ddaff7aa4/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpActivityObserver.idl) [Firefox APIs](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/2124a617b3bc/netwerk/base/nsISocketTransport.idl) [Firebug uses](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/net/httpActivityObserver.js#L22-L23).